# Herbs that Would Relax the Mind but Not Decrease Blood Pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure, herbs, calm-soothing-strategies

Recently, I have been wondering whether there are herbal remedies that would relax the mind from situations related to stress but NOT decrease blood pressure. So far, it has been easy for me to find lists of herbs that have relaxing effects such as from this website, http://www.kitchentablemedicine.com/herbalsedative/, but when I have investigated their effects further I have found that all of them contribute some degree to lessening blood pressure. The reason I am asking this is because a member of my family has naturally low blood pressure and by taking relaxants they have found that it causes them headaches when their blood pressure falls from an already low level. I would be much obliged if someone could clarify whether such remedies are possible or impossible to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot recommend medical treatments on this site.  It's dangerous, especially in a situation where we're talking about symptomatic hypotension.  I can offer you suggestions on where to go for answers:

First, I recommend a relationship with a primary care physician.  A very low baseline BP should be assessed, and precautions discussed with the patient.

Second, I would recommend your relative bring up this concern about relaxation herbal therapies to the PCP.  Most M.D. and D.O. practitioners are not well versed in alternative medicines (even those for which there is mounting evidence of efficacy) but some are.  If they are not, I might recommend seeing an N.D. or other practitioner with thorough knowledge of herbal treatments of mental health.

Third, regardless of whom else he/she sees, psychology/counseling/therapy is an extremely beneficial treatment for stress/anxiety that doesn't involve taking any substances, herbal or otherwise.  It may be able to help get to the root of the problem, rather than just treating symptoms.

Comment: -1: Questions where part of the answer is *see a doctor* are off-topic on Health. [Please do not answer questions which are off-topic.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/753/8212)